# I don't know how to iterate through the elements of an array while reading them

Tags: c, arrays, iteration

I am trying to write a program to find all the vowels in a given string, however I don't know how to get my program to increase my count variable (numVowels)

I've looked for "getting size of array for iteration" etc.. Haven't been able to find anything specific to C.

```
int num_vowels(char string[]){
    //int j;
    int i;
    int numVowels = 0;

    //iterate through string searching for vowels
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(string); i++){

        //if any vowels found
        if (string[i] == 'a' ||string[i] == 'e' ||string[i] == 'i' ||string[i] 
        == 'o' ||string[i] == 'u'){

            //increase count
            numVowels++;
        }
    }
    //print count
    printf("Number of vowels: %d", numVowels);
    return 0;
}
```

Input works fine, it's just i can't get it to print the numvowels, or even find out if it's going through the array.

Edit: I know, it's a long if statement, i'm going to fix that later

Comment: everything looks good to me, except `sizeof(string)` isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: Perhaps replace `sizeof(string)` with `strlen(string)`?

Comment: Use the condition `string[i] != '\0'` in the loop control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write "num_vowels(char string[])" you are **not passing the string** but the address of(pointer to) the first element of the character array "string".

Hence, when you do "sizeof(string)" the result would be the size of the character pointer, which could be either 4 or 8 depending upon the architecture.

As suggested in the comments, you could use "strlen" but please ensure including the "string.h" header.....The solution would be.....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int num_vowels(char string[]){

    int i;
    int numVowels = 0;

    //iterate through string searching for vowels
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++){ //use strlen(string)

    //if any vowels found
      if (string[i] == 'a' ||string[i] == 'e' ||string[i] == 'i' ||string[i] 
    == 'o' ||string[i] == 'u'){

         //increase count
         numVowels++;
      }
   }
  //print count
  printf("Number of vowels: %d", numVowels);

  return 0;
}
```

Or you need not use "strlen" and dereference the pointer directly....
Like so......

```
int num_vowels(char string[]){

  int i;
  int numVowels = 0;

  //iterate through string searching for vowels
  for(; i = *string; string++){ //deference and increment pointer

    //if any vowels found
    if (i == 'a' || i == 'e' || i == 'i' || i 
    == 'o' || i == 'u'){

        //increase count
        numVowels++;
    }
  }
//print count
  printf("Number of vowels: %d", numVowels);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Little help to reduce your conditional `if`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int num_vowels(const char *string){
    int numVowels = 0;
    const char *wordToSearch = "aeiou";

    //loop on string
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        //loop on wordToSearch
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(wordToSearch); j++) {
            if (string[i] == wordToSearch[j]) {
                numVowels++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Number of vowels: %d", numVowels);
    return 0;
}
```